# How to run query to only pull data if specified column contains values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

The query on the DATA sheet should only pull data if specified sheets contain any value in column 3. If there is no value in column 3 then no data should appear on the query.

I have tried to type "CONTAINS VALUE" but that did not work.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CMcxSP86Zc8FajecJmVwlgfe3ComQXUQYpfssjbcyBY/edit?usp=sharing

I am getting an error message

```
=QUERY({'Alex English'!A3:AF;'Zack Jones'!A3:AF;'Aaron Schafer'!A3:AF; 'Abigail Myer'!A3:AF;'Andrew Megronigle'!A3:AF;'April Baker'!A3:AF;'Cameron Staley'!A3:AF;Blank2!A3:AF;'Christin Pylant'!A3:AF;'Chris Burgos'!A3:AF;'Cody Sullivan'!A3:AF;'Colin Pomet'!A3:AF;'Daniel Probst'!A3:AF;Blank!A3:AF;'David Smith'!A3:AF;'Destini Walker'!A3:AF;'George Flores'!A3:AF;'James Murphy'!A3:AF;'Jennifer Piatt'!A3:AF;'Jesse Camire'!A3:AF;'Joel Endel'!A3:AF;'Jordan Richardson'!A3:AF;'Josh Gionti'!A3:AF;'Josh Mech'!A3:AF;'Juan Ortiz'!A3:AF;'Justin Kopka'!A3:AF;'Justin Sanders'!A3:AF;'Kaitlyn Beatty'!A3:AF;'Kevin Lora'!A3:AF;'Kyle Fallon'!A3:AF;'Kyle Silverstein'!A3:AF;'Matthew Nussbaum'!A3:AF;'McKenna Benz'!A3:AF;'Michelle Bullard'!A3:AF;'Michelle Marcos'!A3:AF;'Oliver Santry'!A3:AF;'Ruben Loyo'!A3:AF;'Ryan DelFavero'!A3:AF;'Ryan Kennedy'!A3:AF;'Ryan Morgenlander'!A3:AF;'Shawn Ramrup'!A3:AF;'Tara Knothe'!A3:AF;'Todd Worthington'!A3:AF;'Wesley Miller'!A3:AF;'Zach Coldiron'!A3:AF},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col22 
  where Col3 CONTAINS VALUE", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is: `is not null`

```
=QUERY({'Alex English'!A3:AF;'Zack Jones'!A3:AF;'Aaron Schafer'!A3:AF; 'Abigail Myer'!A3:AF;'Andrew Megronigle'!A3:AF;'April Baker'!A3:AF;'Cameron Staley'!A3:AF;Blank2!A3:AF;'Christin Pylant'!A3:AF;'Chris Burgos'!A3:AF;'Cody Sullivan'!A3:AF;'Colin Pomet'!A3:AF;'Daniel Probst'!A3:AF;Blank!A3:AF;'David Smith'!A3:AF;'Destini Walker'!A3:AF;'George Flores'!A3:AF;'James Murphy'!A3:AF;'Jennifer Piatt'!A3:AF;'Jesse Camire'!A3:AF;'Joel Endel'!A3:AF;'Jordan Richardson'!A3:AF;'Josh Gionti'!A3:AF;'Josh Mech'!A3:AF;'Juan Ortiz'!A3:AF;'Justin Kopka'!A3:AF;'Justin Sanders'!A3:AF;'Kaitlyn Beatty'!A3:AF;'Kevin Lora'!A3:AF;'Kyle Fallon'!A3:AF;'Kyle Silverstein'!A3:AF;'Matthew Nussbaum'!A3:AF;'McKenna Benz'!A3:AF;'Michelle Bullard'!A3:AF;'Michelle Marcos'!A3:AF;'Oliver Santry'!A3:AF;'Ruben Loyo'!A3:AF;'Ryan DelFavero'!A3:AF;'Ryan Kennedy'!A3:AF;'Ryan Morgenlander'!A3:AF;'Shawn Ramrup'!A3:AF;'Tara Knothe'!A3:AF;'Todd Worthington'!A3:AF;'Wesley Miller'!A3:AF;'Zach Coldiron'!A3:AF},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col22 
  where Col3 is not null", 1)
```

[image: 0]